# How to iterate through YAML data from for loop

Tags: java, json, yaml, minecraft

I have problems iterating through a YAML file, 
`config.yml`:

```
motd:
  1: |
    &6MG&1Hub &fWHITELIST &3free
    Factions:
  2: |
    &6MG&1Hub &fWHITELIST &3free
    Bingo:
  3: |
    &6MG&1Hub &fWHITELIST &3free
    Vaaraiant:
  4: |
    &6MG&1Hub &fWHITELIST &3free
    Test:
  5: |
    &6MG&1Hub &fWHITELIST &3free
    PvP:
```

I can read all of them using

```
this.getConfig().get("motd.1").toString();
```

but there is a problem, that I can't access more than one.
I know I could do something like

```
this.getConfig().get("motd."+i).toString();
```

but the problem is, that if I request something like

```
this.getConfig().get("motd.6").toString();
```

the program/plugin would crash.

Keep in mind, that there can be as many 'motds' as the person editing YAML wants to have.

Comment: On [so] you normally insert some file's content by pasting it in, selecting all of the file contents and then clicking `{}` in the edit "bar" (or hit Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
this.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("motd").getValues(false)
```

From the [Bukkit documentation](http://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Configuration_API_Reference#HashMaps):

> To get a *HashMap*, a *ConfigurationSection* must must first be retrieved.
>   You can return the configuration with getConfigurationSection method.
>   The getValues method will return the values in the
>   ConfigurationSection as a map, it takes a boolean which controls if
>   the nested maps will be returned in the map. You can obtain the
>   original map by invoking getValues(false) on the returned
>   ConfigurationSection. Due to the way Java handles generic classes,
>   type information will be lost, thus a cast will need to be performed
>   to set the original type information. The API makes no guarantees that
>   the cast you perform will be safe.

You can then iterate over the `HashMap` as desired.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this with me... Just when I tought that I was getting insane :D thanks!